# Parse millisecond timestamp with DateTime in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I want to create a DateTime object from a millisecond timestamp but that does not seem to work:

```
$timestamp_in_ms = 1546300800000; // int or string no difference
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat("Uv", $timestamp_in_ms));
var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors());
```

This results in:

```
bool(false)
array(4) {
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    [13]=>
    string(12) "Data missing"
  }
}
```

However if I use a slightly different notation it does work:

```
$timestamp_in_ms = "1546300800.000";
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat("U\.v", $timestamp_in_ms));
var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors());
```

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-01-01 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

Yes I can do something like this:

```
$timestamp_with_dot = $timestamp_in_ms / 1000 + "." + $timestamp_in_ms % 1000;
```

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) does not provide any insight in this. Both `U` and `v` are supported.

Anybody more info on this issue? I am running PHP 7.4.10

Comment: Both `U` and `v` can have variable lengths, so PHP cannot know where one stops and the other starts when the dot is missing.

Comment: Yeah that is a good point, for me the milliseconds are always 3 digits so if it starts parsing from the right that would be good for me. But yes this is then more of a documentation thing. I will leave a note on that page to clarify it for other users. So I guess for now I keep the 'dot hack' I currently use.

Answer (score 3):

With a division by 1000 you can convert your millisecond timestamp as a float in seconds.

```
$msTimeStamp = 1600790571478;
$floatSec = $msTimeStamp/1000.0;
```

When using DateTime::createFromFormat, you can also use the "U.u" format. The "u" format should be exactly 6 characters. This can be done with sprintf().

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("U\.u", sprintf('%1.6F',$floatSec));

//test
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u');
//2020-09-22 16:02:51.478000 
//Timezone "+00:00" (UTC)
```

The millisecond timestamp can also be a float and also contain microseconds.
The above code works on 32-bit systems too.

Comment: Thank you, the sprintf is a nice suggestion, makes it more readable then the string concatenation I used. I will try it out!